# To refresh the arraylist after deleting an item from the list

Tags: android, arraylist, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I'm using a Linear Layout inside an Horizontal ScrollView to achieve horizontal slideview. Here when I remove a particular item from custom arraylist, it is not updated in the arraylist. Here's my code for your reference:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.send_enquiry);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    message_editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_editText);
    close_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.close_button);
    senders_list_row_layout = (LinearLayout)   findViewById(R.id.senders_list_row_layout);
    messageSize_textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageSize_textView);
    recepients_horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.recepients_horizontalScrollView);
    attachmentIcon_imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.attachmentIcon_imageView);
    send_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
    recepients_relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.recepients_relLayout);
    successMessage_textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.successMessage_textView);
    creditsEarned_textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.creditsEarned_textView);
    messageSent_imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.messageSent_imageView);


private void sendersList() {

    for (int i = 0; i < sendEnquiry.size(); i++) {

        senders_list_row_layout.addView(viewSendersList(sendEnquiry.get(i)
                .getCpsName(), i));
    }

}


private View viewSendersList(String cpsName, final int position) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.send_enquiry_repeat_items,
            null);

    final TextView sendersName = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.sendersName);
    ImageView closeButton_imageView = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.closeButton_imageView);

    sendersName.setText(cpsName);
closeButton_imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(Q2_SendEnquiryActivity.this,
                    "close button clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            if (sendEnquiry.size() > 1) {

                    sendEnquiry.remove(position);
                    senders_list_row_layout.removeViewAt(position);

                    Log.i("sendEnquiry list size",
                            "sendEnquiry list size: " + sendEnquiry.size());



            } else {
                sendEnquiry.clear();
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Here in this closeButton_imageView.setOnClickListener, I'm removing an item from the custom arrayList. Its works fine for the first time, but after that the position of the items are not updated after an item has been deleted from the arraylist. Also it throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Can anyone help how I can update the customArrayList after removing an item from it?

Comment: hi @Parthiban check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

hi try to remove the view like

```
     senders_list_row_layout.removeView(view);
```

code

private View viewSendersList(String cpsName, final int position) {

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.send_enquiry_repeat_items,
        null);

final TextView sendersName = (TextView) view
        .findViewById(R.id.sendersName);
ImageView closeButton_imageView = (ImageView) view
        .findViewById(R.id.closeButton_imageView);

sendersName.setText(cpsName);
closeButton_imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(Q2_SendEnquiryActivity.this,
                "close button clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        if (sendEnquiry.size() > 1) {

                sendEnquiry.remove(position);
               //not like that
               //senders_list_row_layout.removeViewAt(position);

               //like that
                senders_list_row_layout.removeView(view);

                Log.i("sendEnquiry list size",
                        "sendEnquiry list size: " + sendEnquiry.size());



        } else {
            sendEnquiry.clear();
            finish();
        }
    }
});

return view;
```

}